# How to hide details of column names from other active record models when doing complex joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's a finder method that I am writing in my `Objective` class:

```
def followed_objectives_for_user(user)
  Objective.followed_by_user(user)
  .joins(:resource_objective_links)
  .where('resource_objective_links.resource_id = ? ', self)
end
```

It feels messy to have the knowledge of the `ResourceObjectiveLink`'s `resource_id` column name known to the `Objective` class like this. I tried making a scope on the `ResourceObjectiveLink` class like this, but it can't find it when I chain it in the `followed_objectives_for_user` method in `Objective`:

```
scope :for_resource, ->(resource) { where(resource_id: resource.id) }
```

What is the correct way to hide this information?

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot you just use ActiveRecord relations? Than just

```
User has_many :resource_objective_links
User has_many :objectives, through: :resource_objective_link

Objective has_many :resource_objective_links
Objective has_many :users, through: :resource_objective_links

ResourceObjectiveLink belongs_to :user
ResourceObjectiveLink belongs_to :objective

# And now you can use:
# user = User.find(some_user_id)
# user.objectives 
# => will perform database join and return all Objectives for ResourceObjectiveLink with correct user.id
```